# Trouble running underscore templates

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, typescript

I'm unable to run render HTML from an Underscore template. Here's the code and the error:

```
//Code

class QuestionView extends Backbone.View {
    template:(data:any) => string = null;
    $el = $root;

    constructor(options?:any, question?:Question) {
        super(options);
        this.model = question;
        var q = this;
        require(["text!add-new-question.html"],
            function (html) {
                q.template = _.template(html);
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        var data = this.model.toJSON();
        var html = this.template(data);
        this.$el.html(html);
        return this;
    }
}

class SurveyView extends Backbone.View{
    tagName = "div";
    template:(data:any) => string = null;
    $el = $root;

    constructor(options?:any, survey?:Survey){
        super(options);
        this.template = _.template("<div ><%= enlistQuestions %></div>");
    }

    enlistQuestions():string{
        var questions = "";
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(question:Question){
            var view = new QuestionView(null,question);
            questions += view.template(view.model.toJSON()); // This is line for which the error is shown.
        });
        return questions;
    }
}


//Error
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'template' of object #<QuestionView> is not a function Main.ts:63
(anonymous function) Main.ts:63
j.each.j.forEach underscore.js:79
SurveyView.enlistQuestions Main.ts:61
SurveyView.render Main.ts:69
SurveyView Main.ts:56
(anonymous function) Main.ts:80
```

Comment: Is that `require` call async? That seems to be where `QuestionView` is getting its `template` property. Your code structure is odd, normally you'd say `view.render()` rather than messing around with `view.template` like that, that way you'd be working with DOM nodes and events would work. Looks like you're working with everything as strings of HTML so you've thrown out all of the view's DOM event handling and that is a very strange thing to be doing in a Backbone app.

Comment: @muistooshort. By the way, view() is for rendering on screen. As a convention, what would you do if you just wanted to have the HTML returned instead of rendered.

Comment: No, `view` is for rendering into the view's `el` (i.e. rendering into a DOM node which may or may not be on the screen). I wouldn't bother with a view if all I wanted was HTML, I'd just use templates. The problem is that HTML strings don't have events and if you don't use a view's events then your view is just a template so why bother with all the view machinery at all? If you're not using view events then you don't really have a view at all, you just have an overly complicated function which fills in a template.

Comment: Thanks! Thats great advice. I'm just figuring out Backbone at this point. Does it make sense, to declare templates as "private" as a best practice? Would you do that?

Comment: I don't know TypeScript so I can't say. Generally, anything that the outside world doesn't need to see should (IMO) be private.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the "text" AMD loader plugin.  If not, disregard this answer.

This plugin loads the resource asynchronously and the function supplied to the require statement is called back after the file is loaded.

It appears that the Main is attempting to use the template property on the QuestionView instance before the callback has chances to create it, hence the error.

The text module creates the XHR object and invokes open set the async flag to true.  You need to set this flag to false.  The only way this is possible is to use the onXhr callback and invoke OPEN again setting the async flag to false.

```
requirejs.config({
    config: {
        text: {
            onXhr: function (xhr, url) {
                // This callback is invoked AFTER open but before send.
                // Call open again with the async flag turned off.
                // Not this will also clear any custom headers
                xhr.open('GET', url, /*async*/ false);
                // xhr.setRequestHeader('header', 'value');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

As noted above, any custom HTTP header added by the text module will be cleared when you re-invoke open, but looking at their code there doesn't appear to be any way of supplying extra headers into their 'get' function.